# Android Studio 3.0 NoClassDefFoundError after UPDATE GRADLE to 4+

Tags: gradle

I made a project with two modules - an Android application and a java library. After upgrading studio to v3.0, I get NoClassDefFoundError, only when I run the `main()` method from the java-lib module.

I did not make any changes to the `build.gradle` files, everything was automatic. `implementation` / `api` / `compileOnly` / `runtimeOnly` methods do not change.

I see information about switching to a new plug-in, it says about "Declare flavor dimensions". I have a problem with the translation of this and will soon go mad.

I tried:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-rc-4-all.zip
```

Help me migrate to GRADLE 4+.

Answer (score 0):

You know, I've probably found the answer to my own question. I'm sure that many people have a project with two modules. The Android module works well with the new GRADLE 4+, and the second module as a java project (not a library) does not work with the new GRADLE 4+.

Result of search for the answer: [LibGDX - GitHub](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4698)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions):

> In some cases, you may want to combine configurations from multiple product flavors. For example, you may want to create different configurations for the "full" and "demo" product flavors that are based on API level. To do this, the Android plugin for Gradle allows you to create groups of product flavors, called flavor dimensions. When building your app, Gradle combines a product flavor configuration from each flavor dimension you define, along with a build type configuration, to create the final build variant. Gradle does not combine product flavors that belong to the same flavor dimension.

You must specify at least one `flavorDimension` for Android Studio 3.0 & Gradle 4+

Most importantly, even if you don't have different flavors, you must specify at least one `flavorDimension` & apply it to all your `productFlavors`. That will solve your error. In your `build.gradle` file:

```
flavorDimensions "dummy"
productFlavors {
demo {
    // Assigns this product flavor to the "dummy" flavor dimension.
    dimension "dummy"
    ...
}

full {
    dimension "dummy"
    ...
}
```

Comment: in my case, the android module does not have any problems with the build. Problem with the second module from the project. The second module is the java desktop application (the server for the android application), it will expel the error not when assembling, but when the class is initialized from the deendences (NoClassDefFoundError).